# The game window freezes when calling Application.Quit()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl

I have put together a small project for WebGL, there is an exit button,(Application.Quit()), but when it is called, the window just freezes.

```
public void ExitGame()
{
   print("exitGame");
   Application.Quit();
}
```

[image]

Comment: well what would you expect to happen in the browser when the application is quit?

Comment: I don't even know, for the first time I want to put the game on WebGL, and I was pointed out to this problem. I think I need to go back to the page before the game...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application.Quit()` method is a great way to quit the game on a desktop game but it can't be use to close a browser tab for example in your case, where you are working with WebGL.

What you could instead try is to redirect the player to a new webpage when the player eventually quits the game.

Answer (score 2):

Quitting is used in desktop apps, and isn't designed for use in WebGL builds. Quitting from a WebGL game isn't possible - you can't close the window.

Comment: well you can .. just not this way ;) You can always just call JavaScript code

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I understood, there is a built-in exit button on the site)) I'll just put mine away...